# Value not appearing in the UI after clicking an element in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Scenario:**
I have a search-bar, where after entering some characters, it will auto suggest some values in a list depending on the entered data. There is a box right below the search-bar. After selecting the auto suggested value from the list, the value will be showed in that box.

**Issue:**
After clicking the auto suggested value from the list using Selenium, that value is not appearing in that below box.
But if I click the auto suggested value from the list manually in the UI, it appears in the box.

**DOM structure:**
This is the element for that search-box

```
<input _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" id="typeahead-basic" type="text" typeaheadoptionfield="ContactName" class="form-control form-input-outline ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" placeholder="Search" aria-aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-activedescendant="ngb-typeahead-17-0" aria-aria-owns="ngb-typeahead-17">
```

This is the element for that auto-suggested list box:

```
<typeahead-container class="dropdown open bottom ng-tns-c77-19 dropdown-menu ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; display: block; height: auto; visibility: visible; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 44px, 0px);" _nghost-uxg-c77="" id="ngb-typeahead-19" role="listbox">

<div _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" class="list-group list-group-flush ng-star-inserted"><a _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active ng-star-inserted">
<div _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" class="row ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" class="col-0 pl-1 pr-1 pt-2">
<img _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" src="some_link">
</div>
<div _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" class="col pl-1 pr-1">
<span _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" class="contact-name">user name</span>
<br _ngcontent-uxg-c79="">
<span _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" class="details font-italic">name</span><br _ngcontent-uxg-c79="">
<span _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" class="details">detailed data</span>
</div>
</div>
<!----><!----><!---->
</a><!---->
</div><!----><!----><!----><!---->
</typeahead-container>
```

This is the element for the box that appears below the search bar

```
<div _ngcontent-uxg-c79="" class="card-body"><!----></div>
```

**Steps taken:**

1. I clicked on the element that appeared in the auto-suggested list. The click event occured but nothing appeared in the below box. I also tried JS click.
2. I used Keys.Down and Keys.Enter in the search bar. I also used action.MoveToElement() to focus on that search bar element before giving Key commands. It seems like it has listened to the keyboard event. But the value didn't appear in the below box.

Stuck here for a pretty long time. Please help me if you can.
If any additional info required, feel free to ask.

Comment: Please share your actual code including the link to the page you are working on. Without minimal debugging we can't guess why what you doing not working.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
**All I had to do was first click the search-bar element(i.e the input tag)**, then send the text using SendKeys().
But why it is working now after clicking the input element first, I still don't know. My assumption is, it was not getting the focus of the element. That's why, when the list box appeared after entering value in search-bar, clicking the item from the list didn't appear in the below box.